# Starting an express server from within gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp

I have a `server.js` file in the same directory with `gulpfile.js`.
In `gulpfile.js` I require my `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('./server.js')
```

I want to run it in the `default` task:

```
gulp.task('default' , [ 'build','watch','connect'] , function(){
    gulp.run('express');
});
```

I tried to run it like that but it didn't work. I suppose you can run only tasks in that way. How can I run it in `default` task?

The `server.js` file includes this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 

app.get('/api/test', function(req,res){
  res.send('Hello world!')
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

Comment: you should be able to just run `gulp` from the command line

Comment: when i run gulp with the code like that,it say `task "express" is not in your gulpfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to that would be just replacing my code with the following :

```
gulp.task('default' , [ 'build','watch','connect'] , function(){
  express;
});
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. Since you `require()` the `./server.js` file from outside of your task your server will **always** start, even if you don't run the `default` task. For example running `gulp build` on the command line will start the server as well, whether you want that or not.

Comment: I see! What about `gulp.task('default' , [ 'build','watch','connect'],function(){
 var express = require('./server.js');
});`

Answer (score 4):

The [`gulp-live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-live-server) package allows you (among other things) to start an express server from your own server script:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gls = require('gulp-live-server');

gulp.task('default', [ 'build','watch','connect'], function() {
  var server = gls.new('./server.js');
  return server.start();
});
```

Using the code above you can start your server by running `gulp` on the command line. The server will run until you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.

Comment: Didnt try,but seems to work.A more simple way would be :

`gulp.task('default' , [ 'build','watch','connect'] , function(){
  express;
});`

Answer (score 2):

Quite late at the party, but you might want to use nodemon:

```
const nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
// ...
gulp.task('server', () => {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.js'
  });
});
```